# Google analytics dynamic MTD, YTD, last month "start-date" value

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, klipfolio

I'm trying to access my google analytics app data in Klipfolio through the google analytics query API.

I would like create data sources to dynamically pull MTD, YTD, and last months data.

So far, I've only been able to use today, yesterday, NdaysAgo, and YYYY-MM-DD format for the "start-date" attribute.

Is there a value I can use for "start-date" that will dynamically pull the MTD, YTD, or last months data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For MTD:

```
start-date={date.startOfMonth}
end-date={date.today}
```

For YTD:

```
start-date={date.startOfYear}
end-date={date.today}
```

For last month:

```
start-date={date.addMonths(-1).startOfMonth}
end-date={date.addMonths(-1).endOfMonth}
```